# angular 2: some class members undefined from google maps callback

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get distance between 2 addresses using google maps, 
I want to emit distance to parent component.

but I have problem, that some elements of the child class are not available in that child's google callback method.
`this.directionsDisplay` goes to undefined,
also event emitter member is undefined.

So in Child component i do following steps

event emitter is declared in class head as follow (I want to emit distance between 2 points.):

```
  @Output() onDirectionSet=new EventEmitter<number>();
```

I init data also in `OnInit` function

```
  ngOnInit(){
     if (AppDefinitions.isOffline)
        return;
      this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: {lat: 50.979571, lng: 10.314687},
          zoom: 5
        });
   }
```

and then I am setting direction using following function:

```
      setDirection(origin:string, destination:string){
          this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

          if (AppDefinitions.isOffline)
            return;

          this.directionsService.route({
              origin: origin,
              destination: destination,
              travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }, 
/*google callback*/
            function(response:any, status:any){
                console.log(this.directionsDisplay);
                this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

                if (status === 'OK') {
                      this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                      var directionsModel = new DirectionsModel;
                      directionsModel.distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                      console.log('distance:'+directionsModel.distance);
                      this.onDirectionSet.emit(directionsModel.distance);
                } else {
                      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                }
           });
        }
```

I am calling `setDirectionFunction` in `ngOnChanges`:
`this.from_address` and `this.to_address` are component Inputs

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {   
    if (this.from_address!==undefined && this.to_address!==undefined)
      this.setDirection(this.from_address, this.to_address);
  }
```

**error** from console about undefined class member `this.directionsDisplay` is here:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8kd.png)

Answer (score 1):

The context of your google call back is the undefined. you could use an arrow function to attach the call back function or bind the context to the callback function.

```
this.directionsService.route({
          origin: origin,
          destination: destination,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, 
       /*google callback - use arrow function*/
       (response:any, status:any) => {
            console.log(this.directionsDisplay);
            this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

            if (status === 'OK') {
                  this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                  var directionsModel = new DirectionsModel;
                  directionsModel.distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                  console.log('distance:'+directionsModel.distance);
                  this.onDirectionSet.emit(directionsModel.distance);
            } else {
                  window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
       });
```